# How to store pointers to objects that class doesn't own?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am trying to code two classes FooFactory and Foo. FooFactory initializes an object ToolBox in the constructor and stores it in a unique_ptr as I want that to be cleaned after the factory is destructed. All the instances of Foo should be able to use ToolBox so I am passing ptr to ToolBox object in the constructor of Foo and storing it as bare ptr.

I am new to c++ development so, my questions in the light of general suggestion I heard :

> avoid raw pointers when possible

1. Is the usage of bare ptr to store the tool_box object that Foo doesn't own fine in this case? or Can I do better using smart_ptr?
2. Is the pattern of passing the ptr to ToolBox from the FooFactory class to every new object the correct or is there something better I can do?

Pseudo-code for my classes:

```
class FooFactory {
 public:
  FooFactory() {
    tool_box_.reset(new ToolBox());
  }

  std::unique_ptr<Foo> NewFoo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo(tool_box_.get());
    return foo;
  }
  std::unique_ptr<ToolBox> tool_box_;
}

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(ToolBox* tool_box) {
    tool_box_ = tool_box;
  }
 private:
  // Not Owned
  ToolBox* tool_box;
}
```

Comment: Raw pointer, as you have in the code snippet, is suitable for a non-owning pointer.  NewFoo should be:  `std::unique_ptr<ToolBox> NewFoo() {...` because that is returning an *owned* pointer.

Comment: Typically the advice is to "avoid *owning* raw pointers".  Non-owning raw pointers are generally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `factory` would normally never control the lifetime of an object. It should hand out an appropriate pointer, preferably a `std::unique_ptr` and the caller determines it's lifetime.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Box
{
public:
    Box() {}
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<Box> &box)
    : m_box(box)
    {
    }
    virtual ~Foo(){}

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    Box *getBox()
    {
        return m_box.get();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Box> m_box;
};

class FooFactory
{
public:
    FooFactory()
    {
        m_box = std:make_shared<Box>();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> CreateFoo()
    {
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(m_box);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Box> m_box;
};

int main()
{
    FooFactory factory;
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = factory.CreateFoo();

    foo->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to keep the factory lightweight as well but how would I go about it - if I want all the Foo classes to use a common ToolBox? Should I use something like java static variables inside Foo?

Comment: The `factory` knows how to construct an object. So this is the place where it would add this toolbox you need. If the `Toolbox` is a "global" object and for others the same, then you can create it inside your factory.

Comment: So `factory` should construct the `tool_box` but should not store it? Since the requirement is 'there should only be one instance of tool_box object shared accros Foo objects'. If I pass it using `std::uniqe_ptr` to every Foo created without storing it inside the `factory` object - I can't let every Foo access the same tool_box?

Comment: Depending on the Toolbox you don't need to create it with a shared pointer, but then you need to ensure the liftime of the factory because it holds the toolbox. In this case a raw pointer would be sufficient. Depends on how your toolbox is constructed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So store it in shared_ptr both in factory and Foo to make sure even when Factory is deleted Foo objects can still access tool box and when last of them is gone it is cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

One way to store a non-owning "pointer" to an object (while coupling the class with that object) would be to store a reference (or perhaps a const reference) instead of a pointer.

In my experience, the constraint of needing to initialize the class with that reference helps hierarchical design and simplifies lifetime management.

Comment: Thanks, so can I safely say that all read-only not-owning objects can be passed/stored as const refs?

Comment: It is generally discouraged to have reference data members. For the purposes of storing references in classes, it is usually better to use a pointer-to-const instead of a reference data members almost always means the class will be non-assignable.

Comment: I'd say it probably boils down on whether you'd want a nullable state to be valid. Of course, with the necessary constructors I think that this can still be enforced with a pointer-to-const, as you said.